# Узнать гравитацию DrawerLayout'a (где выдвигается справа или слева)

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Я использую Drawerlayout и он открывается справа и слева
Теперь мне нужно чтобы когда Drawer открывался справа то воспроизводился один код, а если слева то другой код как мне можно нужно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете `Drawerlayout`, то скорее всего для идентификации открытия Drawer'a используете `onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)` класса `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Так вот, как вариант для левого и правого Drawer'ов установить соответствующие тэги LEFT и RIGHT, и уже в onDrawerOpened проверять:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    String tag = (String) drawerView.getTag();
    switch (tag) {
        case "LEFT":
            ......
            break;
        case "RIGHT":
            ......
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм может я чего-то не понимаю, но у меня код не работает просто я новичок в программировании. Так вот когда я вставляю ваш код в свой то LEFT и RIGHT подсвечиваются красным затем я решаю убрать switch и вместо него написать `String tag = (String) drawerView.getTag(START); Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;` но при выводе на экране отображается пустой Toast. Тем не менее спасибо за ответ я это ценю.

Comment: @Snuiper228 красным подсвечивается потому что это должны быть строки, оберните в ковычки(см. обновленный ответ).

Comment: @Snuiper228 + не забудьте установить соответствующие теги для фрагментов.

Comment: Спасибо ваш способ сработал!